# MySQL rows deleted on varchar column

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where I am stuck. I want to delete all the records in a table of varchar column. The query is to be:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column = 'value'
```

But istead of this query I mistakenly executed the following query

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE column = 0
```

All the records in the table are deleted. Why?
Any suggestion

Comment: Probably this has to do with casting rules, and all varchar values, when cast to integers, became 0, or something like this.

Comment: so how to prevent from this situation??

Comment: Dont compare a varchar column to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you tell us more about why you thought to do this, perhaps more can also be said.